# Cohomology Group basis

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm reading a text on Complex Torus and Abelian Variety and at a time is written as follows:

The cohomology group $H^{1}(T,\mathcal O_{T})$ has a basis

$w_{j}=d\overline{z}_{j}, j=1,2,...,g,$

as the Dolbeault cohomology group, where $(z_{1}, z_{2},...,z_{g})$ are coordinates of $\mathbb{C}^{g.}$

1) What does it mean $H^{1}(T,\mathcal O_{T})$ has a basis

$w_{j}=d\overline{z}_{j}, j=1,2,...,g$ ?

2) What is Dolbeault cohomology group?

If you can help me with references would be great!

Thank You

Comment: The Dobeault cohomology $H^1(T,O_T)$ is a vector space, a the claim is that the 1-forms listed constitute a basis — the meaning of this is explained in every linear algebra course! As for what is Dolbeault cohomology, it is quite difficult to answer this without knowing what your background is...

Comment: I do not know about cohomology did not know for example that $ H ^ {1} (T, \mathcal O_ {T}) $ was a vector space. could you please help me with references ? thank you

Comment: I don't know your reference, but if you don't know cohomology, I suspect you might not have the background to read it.

Comment: A book on tori is going to be difficult if you don't know cohomology. [This book by Huybrechts](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540212904) is popular these days for basic complex geometry but it seems like one should know the story for real manifolds first. There are too many books on the latter to list here, but I'm sure there are relevant questions on this site.

Comment: Also, it seems like you're using [Dolbeault's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolbeault_cohomology#Dolbeault.27s_theorem) here implicitly. It might be dangerous to do this early on in life. [Also on that page you will find the definition of the Dolbeault groups. I admit that "groups" is a little misleading but it's too late to change now.]

Comment: Danger is part of life! :)